# create context menu for fragment in android

Tags: android, android-fragments

i have two activity in my android app. one is list view and another one is ListDetailActivity.

i want to implement multipan layout so when this app run on tablat (Large screen) both screen will be in same screen. for that we have implement as a fragment and combine in one fragmentActivity.

like this image 
[image]

but how can i implement context menu for both fragment on a single screen.

is it possible?